# Trimming both 0 and trailing/leading spaces doesn't give results - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the below situation in the database where accounts could have leading 0 and white spaces.

[image]

If I use  `TRIM(TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM account_ref)) as account_ref_trimmed`, I get:

[image]

Question, is it correct to put trim inside the trim? Secondly, why in row 5, there is still a leading 0?

Comment: Trim spaces first and then the zeroes.

Comment: @forpas, it worked - feel silly. Is there a source on the precedence of trim operations or what I asked is a common sense?

Comment: You need to read (and write) nested function calls from inside to outside. The inner call is executed/evaluated first.

Comment: Understood! @forpas, withdrawing the question about precendece. Thank you, Paul!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim the spaces and then the zeroes:

```
TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM TRIM(account_ref))
```

When you try to trim the zeroes first, any values that have spaces at the beginning and then zeroes will only be trimmed off of spaces.
As for your question about precedence it is indicated by the nested parentheses.